# Spring Batch - unable persist reader type

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

after upgrading to Spring Batch 3.0.2 faced the following issue: chunk step fails trying to persist reader object which is not JPA Entity and not Serializable.

```
@Autowired
protected PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

@Autowired 
protected JobRepository jobRepository;

[...]

@Bean
@JobScope
public Step processFileStep() {
    return new StepBuilder("process-file", jobRepository)
        .<Row, Matching>chunk(chunkSize, transactionManager)
        .reader(reader())
        .processor()
        .writer(writer())
        .build();
}
```

Row type here is `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row` which is passed by custom Apache POI Excel item reader. `transactionManager` and `jobRepository` are autoconfigured by Spring Data JPA.

On this step the following exception occurs:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity [class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.contains(SessionImpl.java:1604)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter.doWrite(JpaItemWriter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter.write(JpaItemWriter.java:93)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter$$SpringCGLIB$$0.write(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:170)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:297)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:227)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:389)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:313)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:256)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:362)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:206)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:139)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:241)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:227)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy73.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:153)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:417)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:132)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:316)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:157)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher.run(TaskExecutorJobLauncher.java:70)
    at org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler.launch(JobLaunchingMessageHandler.java:53)
    at org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingGateway.handleRequestMessage(JobLaunchingGateway.java:71)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleWithMetrics(AbstractMessageHandler.java:90)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendWithMetrics(AbstractMessageChannel.java:344)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:324)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:297)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:484)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:339)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:268)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:232)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleWithMetrics(AbstractMessageHandler.java:90)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendWithMetrics(AbstractMessageChannel.java:344)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:324)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:297)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:196)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.messageReceived(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:474)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:460)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:412)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:341)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.getEntityDescriptor(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:416)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.contains(SessionImpl.java:1601)
    ... 106 common frames omitted
```

Batch configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(tablePrefix = "batch.batch_")
public class BatchConfiguration {
}
```

JPA configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("XXX.common.repository")
@EntityScan("XXX.common.model")   
public class JpaConfig {
}
```

JPA dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Before this updage from Spring Batch 2.6.6 to Spring Batch 3.0.2 `chunk()` method did not have `transactionManager` parameter and this code worked as intended.

It seems like Map-based job repository should work in this case but it's not a production-ready solution.
Is there any way to use `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row` (or any other non-JPA object) as reader output with newer Spring Batch version with persistent storage?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The type of input items should not necessarily be managed by JPA/Hibernate (ie it does not have to be an entity), but it seems like it is scanned by the JPA auto-configuration. Since your step is changing the input type to another type (`Matching`), only the output type should be managed by JPA. Please share your JPA configuration to be able to help you efficiently.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, updated my question - added JPA configuration. `Matching` type is entity managed by JPA, located at `XXX.common.model`. 
+ `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation in main class.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, managed to find a silly mistake in my code - processor was never assigned to this step. So `ItemWriter` actually tried to persist `Row` objects. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved your issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By debugging Spring Batch source code found that `JpaItemWriter` tries to persist list of `Row`'s instead of `Matching` ones.

Found a silly mistake in my code:

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public Step processFileStep() {
    return new StepBuilder("process-file", jobRepository)
        .<Row, Matching>chunk(chunkSize, transactionManager)
        .reader(reader())
        .processor()
        .writer(writer())
        .build();
}
```

this part is missing an actual processor.
So my POI list of `Row`'s passed directly to JPA writer. I've made my processor dummy for testing purposes and never checked that it was actually called.

Correct `Step` code is

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public Step processFileStep() {
    return new StepBuilder("process-file", jobRepository)
        .<Row, Matching>chunk(chunkSize, transactionManager)
        .reader(reader())
        .processor(processor())
        .writer(writer())
        .build();
}
```

Can't believe it couldn't find this issue for at least a few days.